# Insert key/value with spaces using variable into associative array and return it to parent function

Tags: bash, array

Have 2 functions, child and parent.

Child function building an associative array, and returning it to another associative array in parent function

Key and values are strings that always vary according to the data, in some of those strings, it is possible that a white space can appear, which is OK.

But than `must use subscript when assigning associative array` message appears, and the value/key are devided until the first space.

Parent code:

```
declare -A TEST="$(child_func)"
# Print             
for key in  "${!TEST[@]}" ; do
                    echo -e "key: $key\n"
                    echo -e "value: ${TEST[$key]}\n"
                done
```

Child code:

```
local _exec_result=$(timeout ${EXECUTION_TIMEOUT} /bin/bash ${cmd})
local _exec_code=$?
local _key="${_exec_result}"
local _val="${_exec_code}"
declare -A _exec_dict+=(["${_key}"]="${_val}")
# Final return
if (( ${#_exec_dict[@]} ))
then 
    echo '('
    for key in "${!_exec_dict[@]}" ; do
        echo "[${key}]=${_exec_dict[${key}]}"
    done
    echo ')'
fi
```

Works for values:

```
key: 0
value: bbb
```

Output:

```
key: 0
value: bbb
```

Not works for:

```
key: 0
value: b bb
```

Output:

```
TEST: bb: must use subscript when assigning associative array
    key: 0
    value: b
```

Bottom line: how can I handle with spaces in variables that eventually I insert to associative array's key/value

How to return, used [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975967/returning-a-dictionary-from-a-bash-function) solution

Comment: We have noticed that the "_Bourne-Again_" Shell-Scripting Environment is extremely sensitive while handling Single-Quote-Terminated versus Double-Quote-Terminated Character Strings. Try declaring your `_val` Local Variable using Single-Quotes instead.

Comment: The error message mentions `TEST`, not `_exec_dict`. What are you doing with `TEST` in your *actual* code?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski your right, forgot to mention this. `_exec_dict` is child-function dictionary that is returned to parent-func, into `TEST` dictionary. Updated the question

Comment: The error is generated by this line: `declare -A TEST="$(child_func)"`. It looks what the `child_func` prints must contain quotes in proper places; and it doesn't. Is `child_func` a function? Is there a reason it cannot operate on `TEST` directly? It would be more robust than generating *code-like* quoted output. However if you really need to pass data by printing it then [forget about `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618).